# How to run managed-vm-gae example code locally

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-bigtable

I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/java/managed-vm-gae)
to get a Bigtable client up and running in Google Managed VMs. But is there a way to run this locally? Reason is that deploying the code remotely in development is a pain.

Normally I can use `dev_appserver.sh` to run GAE app locally. But when I run it, I'm getting this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Jetty ALPN has not been
>   properly configured.

Which means we need to include ALPN library? Since our codebase is in Java 7,  I used this ALPN version: `7.1.3.v20150130`.

I then tried again with this:

```
dev_appserver.sh --jvm_flag=-Xbootclasspath/p:/Users/shouguoli/tmp/alpn-boot-7.1.3.v20150130.jar
```

still getting this error:

> Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException:
>   The API package 'urlfetch' or call 'Fetch()' was not found.

How do you get it to work locally?

Comment: I'm working on that right now - hope to update the repo by tomorrow or Wednesday.

Comment: Close -- hopefully by EoD tomorrow or it probably won't happen 'til Jan.

Comment: haha, up votes/badges/reputations, what do you need to get it done!?!? :)

Comment: Got really close, flying tomorrow, will try again Monday afternoon (or earlier).  I know how important this is and I think it is finally within our grasp.

Comment: any updates to this?  :)

Answer (score 1):

The [sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/java/jetty-managed-vm) was updated last week.  It's based on the java 8 compat runtime, which means that you have access to most of the App Engine API's including Users, Task Queues, and Datastore.

There is a new [Netty TCNative](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-tcnative-boringssl-static/1.1.33.Fork13) module that uses Boring SSL.

To use it with the `pom.xml` in the sample, do:

`mvn clean -Pmac jetty:run -Dbigtable.projectID=<your-project> -Dbigtable.clusterID=<your-cluster> -Dbigtable.zone=<your-zone>`

To use on Windows, use `-Pwindows` instead of `-Pmac`.  For linux, omit the Profile `-P` as it's the default.

To deploy:

`mvn clean gcloud:deploy -Dbigtable.projectID=<your-project> -Dbigtable.clusterID=<your-cluster> -Dbigtable.zone=<your-zone>`

**NOTE** - it is advisable to do the clean between running locally and running remotely as the TCNative module is currently specific to the platform the code runs on.

We are in the process of updating all of our samples to use TCNative, we hope to have this by 3/10/16.